# Firebase Android: File upload cancellation

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

Does `uploadTask.cancel()` work only with large files? I am trying to upload a file of which it works but also the file upload should be cancellable of which in my case it only works with large files small files upload even though I have cancelled the file upload.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What is probably happening is that the small files are uploaded very fast and by the time you call `cancel()`, they have already been uploaded. You didn't provide any code, but I assume you're executing `uploadTask.cancel()` in the click of a button. So I recommend that you check if the task is completed before cancelling it. And if it is, delete the small file. You can use this code for that:

```java
    if (!uploadTask.isComplete()) {
        //Upload is not complete yet, let's cancel
        uploadTask.cancel();
    } else {
        //Upload is complete, but user wanted to cancel. Let's delete the file
        uploadTask.snapshot.ref.delete();
        // storageRef.delete(); // will delete all your files
    }
```

Comment: Won't storageRef.delete(); delete all the files in my storage ? Here's how my storage reference looks like :-    StorageReference storageRef = storage.getReferenceFromUrl(Constants.fbStoragePathImage);  and this is how I upload it to the storage  UploadTask uploadTask=  storageRef.child(pictureRefName ).putFile(fileUri);

Comment: I just used the `storageRef` as an example. But you're right, it will delete all your files. You should use `storagetRef.child(pictureRefName).delete()` instead.